# Can we auto create TestCases from the PBI Acceptance Criteria?

Tags: test-management, testcase

Is there a way to auto create Test Cases from the Acceptance criteria defined in TFS?

Answer (score 1):

There appears to be a VS Powertool *TFS Tester Power Tool-Auto Create Test Cases from PBI Acceptance Criteria* in beta that will allow for this to be done.

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/5826c7c8-852e-4239-96bf-e2ba4ab9dab6